# Spring controller serialization synchronization

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

Let's say I have a Spring controller like this

```
@RestConroller
class MyController {

    MyObject myObject;

    @GetMapping
    synchronized MyObject get() {
        return myObject;
    }

    // Runs in another thread
    void f() {
        for (;;) {
            synchronized {
                myObject.modify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the Spring code that serializes myObject to JSON and f will simultaneously try to access myObject as soon as get() returns. Is there a way to prevent this besides returning a deep copy of myObject?

Answer (score 0):

Use myobject property in synchronized block

Synchronized(myobject) {} or you can use any other concurrency locks. Also if you want deep copy you can serialize and deserialize myobject by object serialization or json serialization.

Maybe you can check method synchronization or block synchronization. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-block-synchronization-java/amp/